# Check how many times an App Service pulls an image from an Azure Container Repository

Tags: azure, docker, azure-web-app-service, azure-monitoring, azure-container-registry

I have an Azure App Service that runs a Linux container which is pulled from a tag in an Azure Container Registry. If I enable continuous deployment in the App Service and overwrite the tag associated with it, the App Service will automatically update itself by pulling the image from the associated tag. Since this process of deployment from the tag happens automatically, I want to know when and how many times did the App Service pull from the tag and updated itself, all the way from the very first instance that it happened. The deployment and Activity Logs of the App Service does not show what I've been looking for, nor the Azure Monitor logs and metrics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at this article ?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-diagnostics-audit-logs

You should be able to configure diagnostic logs on the ACR and store those in Log Analytic to view the different pull counts.

Comment: I was able to get all the pulls from my registry with the help of this. Thanks.